# Camera plugin is not working in phonegap app for ios

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am new to ios development. 
I have created an app with phonegap its working fine with android. 
But for IOS its not working. I have installed all the plugins.

Right now i am testing the camera plugin.

But its showing the following error.

```
 Error: Can't find variable: Camera   ionic.bundle.js:20306
    clickPicture@file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/CF215D1D-130F-4901-B935-C086A94A5579/test_proj.app/www/app/common/camera-service.js:11:38
_takePicture@file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/CF215D1D-130F-4901-B935-C086A94A5579/test_proj.app/www/app/registration/registeration-controller.js:54:44
$parseFunctionCall@file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/CF215D1D-130F-4901-B935-C086A94A5579/test_proj.app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21044:23
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/CF215D1D-130F-4901-B935-C086A94A5579/test_proj.app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:53439:21
$eval@file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/CF215D1D-130F-4901-B935-C086A94A5579/test_proj.app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23100:28
$apply@file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/CF215D1D-130F-4901-B935-C086A94A5579/test_proj.app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23199:28
file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/CF215D1D-130F-4901-B935-C086A94A5579/test_proj.app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:53438:19
eventHandler@file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/CF215D1D-130F-4901-B935-C086A94A5579/test_proj.app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11713:25
dispatchEvent@[native code]
triggerMouseEvent@file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/CF215D1D-130F-4901-B935-C086A94A5579/test_proj.app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2863:20
tapClick@file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/CF215D1D-130F-4901-B935-C086A94A5579/test_proj.app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2852:20
tapTouchEnd@file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/CF215D1D-130F-4901-B935-C086A94A5579/test_proj.app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:2975:13
```

there are two config.xml files in my project 
one is in `root` folder and other one is in `staging` folder

i made entry of camera plugin in both files as well as tried with individuals file.

i have tried with two types of entries in config.xml

first one :

```
 <feature name="Camera">
            <param name="ios-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
     </feature>
```

Second one

```
<feature name="Camera">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera" />
    </feature>
```

But its continuously showing the same error.

here is my project file structure.
i am trying to fix it from last two days. But dont know where i am wrong.

[image]

Comment: you don't have to add the feature tag in any of the config.xml, it's added (on the config.xml on staging) on plugin install. Are you waiting for the device ready? try to uninstall and reinstall the plugin

Comment: yes. I have done the same. We are waiting for the device ready. And also i   reinstalled the plugin 2-3 times. But nothing works for me ):

Comment: I've just tested with latest camera plugin "cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera" and ionic 1.6.1 and it's working fine, which versions are you using?

Comment: here is my camera plugin "org.apache.cordova.camera 0.3.6 "Camera" and my ionic version is 1.0.0-rc.5

Comment: Remove you camera plugin and add the lattest camera plugin with cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera, 0.3.6 is very old and your problem might be a bug

Comment: thanks for you help and time. I was just missing the command "cordova platform update ios". now its working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spent a lot of time. I found that the plugin was not updating `ionic.bundle.js` for that i just run the `cordova platform update ios` command.

And now its working fine.